# Finding number of errors in an eclipse project using compilation unit

Tags: java, eclipse

By means of Markers i was able to find the number of errors(marked red by the eclipse).Is it possible to find these errors by use of "compilation unit"??If yes then how to do it using the compilation unit??Plz suggest.

Comment: Is my answer eligible as resolving one?

Answer (score 1):

At the moment I'm using Indigo, so that my answer is referred to this release of Eclipse.
On options of *Marker View* you can change *Configure Content* options and create a new configuration. With this new configuration, I suggest you to change *Scope* to *On selected element and its children*. Doing so, if you click on a package or a single file (i think this is your definition of 'compilation unit'), you can filter problems using selected element. This also gives you number of problems as the filter you applied.